# Newline in php not working

Tags: php, newline

In my code I have several sentences in one paragraph as I would like to not get spacing between them. However I can't seem to get them each to begin on a newline.

```
  <p class ="BasicP"> Datum: <?php echo $Datum;"\r\n"?>
    Betreft: <?php echo $Betreft;"<br>"?>
    Offertenr: <?php echo $Offertenr;"\n"?>
    <p>
```

And this outputs:
Datum: Betreft: Offertenr:

I would like it to output:

Datum:

Betreft:

Offertenr:

Each of them starting on a new line.

I've tried `<br>, PHP_EOL and newline`.

If anyone could tell me what exactly is wrong and how to do it, that would be appreciated.

I added what I tried to the code, none of the tree get me a new line for some reason..

Comment: edit your question to hold the exact code that you tried those with

Comment: just simply use <br />. You are using <p>, so why not use both tags?

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich OP states: *"I've tried `<br>`"* - Edit: OP has parse errors, that's why.

Comment: You really need to show how u use the line breaks as u have stated

Comment: `<?php echo $Betreft;"<br>"?>` is a syntax parse/error. That's why it's not working. Same thing goes for all your other ones.

Comment: I don't understand. You said you're using a single `<p>` to avoid spacing, yet what you want seems to be spacing. Use several `<p>` then, or add `<br>`. What do you mean `<br>` doesn't work?

Comment: @domdom Basically by using seperate <p> tags it gives me blank space between each line and I try avoiding that by putting it all in one.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - Always, during development/testing.

Comment: `echo $Betreft;"<br>"` does not make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help people, It is solved.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options:

**Sepperate paragraphs**:

```
<p class ="BasicP">Datum: <?php echo $Datum;?></p>
<p class ="BasicP">Betreft: <?php echo $Betreft;?></p>
<p class ="BasicP">Offertenr: <?php echo $Offertenr;?></p>
```

**Line break**:

```
<p class ="BasicP">
    Datum: <?php echo $Datum;?><br/>
    Betreft: <?php echo $Betreft;?><br/>
    Offertenr: <?php echo $Offertenr;?>
<p>
```

Or print it as *code*:

```
<pre>
    Datum: <?php echo $Datum;?>
    Betreft: <?php echo $Betreft;?>
    Offertenr: <?php echo $Offertenr;?>
</pre>
```

This has noting to do with PHP. A simple HTML question.

Comment: Sure, but the question is off-topic; it's a parse error.

Comment: The Line break solution did the trick, thank you. I must've done something a tiny bit wrong.

Comment: ,,, or set `whitespace: pre;` in the `BasicP` class in the stylesheet.